# Zoo Visitor and/or EE login forms fail to login using email

Tags: email, forms, login, zoo-visitor

If memory serves correctly users where able to login using either email or username in a standard login form until a few days ago. The site uses zoo_visitor latest version and has been updated to EE 2.6.1 to handle the new zoo visitor forgotten password form.

Login using username/password on both Zoo and EE login forms is fine. Try using email and error:

> The existing username and/or password you submitted are not valid

Any ideas? Is this because of the updates? My next port o' call is stepping through the php, thought id ask here first.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a setting in the Zoo Visitor settings page.

```
Set username as email (login is email) [Yes/No]
```

So you can choose which one you want to use as the login when using Zoo Visitor forms.

If you wanted to use both (either/or) then use the standard EE login form in combination with [NSM Email Login](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/nsm-email-login).

Comment: Thanks very much! Needed both and NSM Email has sorted it. I am just so surprised this isn't a standard feature/setting in EE. 
Also - despite not being what I wanted, I did try the Zoo Visitor setting you mention, it had no effect - I assume it is buggy.

Comment: They may add it into the core one day but when other addons have popped up to fill the void I think it takes a lesser priority on their list. With regards to logging in with the email address using Zoo Visitor that should work however. I think you may just need to set the option to 'Yes' **before** registration. ZV only allows one or the other however.